# AWS DynamoDB best way to create a table and retrieve data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have the following table:

Table1

- Key
- Attribute1
- Attribute2

I need to query by Attribute1 and Attribute2 (and operator).

What is the best way to design the table (with secondary index, global secondary index etc) and what the best way (performance) do retrieve data by the attributes? Only by scan?

Answer (score 0):

Assume your query requirement is 
key EQ keyvalue AND Attribute1 OPERATOR1 value_1 AND Attribute2 OPERATOR2 value_2

/* where keyvalue is the value of the hash key you want to use, value_1 and value_2 are values corresponding to Attribute1 and Attribute2 respectively */

In such case, define a table with HashKey = key, RangeKey = Attribute1 or Attribute2 - whichever has higher cardinality. Lets assume Attribute1 has higher cardinality

While creating query, the **KeyConditions section** will have

Key (i.e. hash key) EQ keyvalue
Attribute1 (i.e. Range Key) OPERATOR1 value_1

/* OPERATOR1 can be one of the following operators - EQ | LE | LT | GE | GT | BEGINS_WITH | BETWEEN */

The **QueryFilter section** will have

AND

Attribute2 (i.e. non-key attribute) OPERATOR2 value_2

/* OPERATOR2 can be one of the following operators - EQ | NE | LE | LT | GE | GT | NOT_NULL | NULL | CONTAINS | NOT_CONTAINS | BEGINS_WITH | IN | BETWEEN */

Please note the items will be fetched based on hash key and Attribute1 and then they will be filtered based on Attribute2. For more details on the Query API please refer to this documentation http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html

If you want queries to satisfy the following scenarios

1. key = keyvalue AND Attribute_1 OPERATOR1 Value_1
2. Key = keyvalue AND Attribute_2 OPERATOR1 Value_2

Then you can define a table with HashKey = key, RangeKey = Attribute_1 and a Global Secondary Index (GSI) or a Local Secondary Index (LSI) with Index HashKey = key and Index RangeKey = Attribute2.

For a comparison between GSI and LSI please refer to the following documentation
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SecondaryIndexes.html

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Vivek. But in my case, i won't use the key value for search and I'll use both attributes at the same time.